# Setting up postfix as relay but also as smtp

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, centos6

I've set up a postfix server that relays email to another server, this is working fine. I managed this using the **relayhost** variable.

example:

```
relayhost = 192.2.123.25
```

This means all incoming emails are sent to that server, which is good. However, local email sent from the server where postfix is installed, for example using:

```
$ mail -s "subject example" mike@example.com
```

are also being sent to the relay host, however, I only want this server to use relayhost for incoming email, for outgoing emails it should use itself as smtp. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Relayhost sets your next hop for all email that hits the postfix server.  You could use transport maps to forward emails for a specific domain.

`/etc/postfix/transport`

```
example.com   smtp:
.example.com  smtp:
*         smtp:[192.2.123.25]
```

`postmap /etc/postfix/transport`

`postfix -e transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport`

[RTFM](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)